# Regex to remove [?] from line?

Tags: regex

What would be the appropriate regex to remove all the [?] from the line as such:

```
/Hello[1]/World[2]/Foo[3]
/Bar[3]/Foo[2]
```

etc.

Comment: Will the content between the brackets always be a number? Will it always be a single digit?

Comment: It will always be an integer (so not necessarily single digit, but a whole number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any symbol beetwin `[]` replace regex `\[.+?\]` with empty string
for digits `\[\d+?\]`

Comment: This does not work, for example try this: `System.out.println("/hello[4]/world[2]".replace("[\\d+?]", ""));`

Comment: Sorry, still does not work: `System.out.println("/hello[4]/world[2]".replace("\\[.+?\\]", ""));`

Comment: Apologies, my mistake, I had to use `replaceAll` ... thnx!

Answer (score 1):

If the number can be negative, then `\[-?\d+\]` or `\[-?[0-9]+\]`.

Answer (score 0):

I noted you mentioning `"/hello[4]/world[2]".replace("[\\d+?]"`. Besides of the missing shield symbols, you have to use String.replaceAll() or String.replaceFirst() if you want to apply regular expressions.